# Haskell update sublist by index

Tags: haskell

Trying to learn Haskell, I have come across this simple pattern a few times recently:

Lets say I have a list of something and I want to update all elements in a sublist, for example from index i to j.

All the solutions I can come up with feels really hacky and bad, like this example:

```
import qualified Data.Sequence as S

increment :: Int -> Int -> S.Seq Int -> S.Seq Int
increment i j sq | i <= j = increment (i + 1) to (S.adjust (+1) i sq)
                 | otherwise = sq
```

I guess I would make it even worse with a list.

Anyone know some easy way to do this? I have tried searching, and also looking at the standard libaries (Data.Array, Data.Vector etc) but there's something about the way it's written that makes my eyes bleed a little bit and I want some human advice

Comment: You mean decrement all the elements between index `i` and `j`? "Decrement all the integers 0 <= i <= j < N" is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: It might be obvious to you, but what is `S`? Please add the relevant import statement.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it should become clear from the function definition

Comment: @Amoz: strictly speaking if you say "*Lets say I have a list of integers of length N and I want to increment all the integers 0 <= i <= j < N*", then it means you want to decrement elements in a list for which the integers "*0 <= i <= j < N*" hold, but *0 <= i <= j < N* are no integers, it is a boolean (well unless we extend the "<=" operator, etc.). so the definition right now, does not make much sense.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks I get your point. I thought the word "index" in the title could be sufficient. I edited my post! thanks for feedback

Answer (score 5):

> I have tried searching, and also looking at the standard libaries (Data.Array, Data.Vector etc) but there's something about the way it's written that makes my eyes bleed a little bit and I want some human advice

Yes, it is straight forward to use `Data.Array` to dual with problem that involved index. For immutable array, you can use `accum` function to update the elements of array with list of `(index, value)` pair to specify the index and value.

For example, assume we need add 1 to elements of array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` from index 2 to 4.

Fristly, construct an array from list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`:

```
testArray = let xs = [1..10] in listArray (0, length xs-1) xs
```

and apply `accum` function to the array:

```
increment' i j ary = accum (+) ary (zip [i..j] (repeat 1))
```

Note that `(zip [i..j] (repeat 1))` constructs a list of pairs, if `i = 2 and j = 4` gives:

```
[(2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1)]
```

the first value of pair is the index of array and the second is second argument of `(+)`, `accum` retrieve the value of specific index and apply `(+1)` to the value, that is just what we want. To test it:

```
elems $ increment' 2 4 testArray
```

gives

```
[1,2,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Otherwise, if you just want to replace the old value of array with new value and don't care what the old value is. `accum` function can be applied in this situation as well. For example, assume to replace elements of index 2 to 4 with `0`:

```
accum (flip const) testArray (zip [2..4] (repeat 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient approach is to split the sequence at the two endpoints, use `fmap` on the middle part, then join the parts back together.

```
increment :: Int -> Int -> S.Seq Int -> S.Seq Int
increment i j sq = sq0 S.>< fmap (+ 1) sq1 S.>< sq2
  where
    (sq01, sq2) = S.splitAt (j + 1) sq
    (sq0, sq1) = S.splitAt i sq01
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to be thinking more functionally about this.  If we look at:

```
S.adjust :: Int -> (a -> a) -> S.Seq a -> S.Seq a
```

It takes an index to adjust, the adjustment to apply, and a sequence, and returns a new sequence.  To adjust a bunch of elements, we adjust the first, then adjust the second to the result of the first adjustment, and so on.  First we can make a list of all the adjustments we want to make:

```
adjustments :: [S.Seq Int -> S.Seq Int]
adjustments = [ S.adjust i (+1) | i <- [lower..upper] ]
```

(take note: this is a list of functions).   Then I want to apply one after the next to a seed sequence.  So if the list ended up being

```
adjustments = [inc1, inc2, inc3]
```

We want to get

```
inc1 (inc2 (inc3 seq0))
```

where `seq0` is the initial incoming sequence.  Does this approach make sense; is it enough to get you started?